# Wordpress and Vimeo end of movie

Tags: jquery, wordpress, vimeo, froogaloop

On a Wordpress homepage, I have embed a Vimeo video, when the video ends, it needs to go to portfolio page.

I found many examples of Vimeo API and about Froogaloop, like https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api, but I tried and no one worked. I also found that for Wordpress the jQuery has to be a bit different, so I used the code that should be working in Wordpress. I use Avada as a theme and I have a CODE BOX in the page construction where I have entered this code:

```
<script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>

<div class='fullscreen_block fw_background bg_video'>
    <iframe id="vimeovideo" style='left: 0% !important; top: 0% !important;' src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/158002922?autoplay=1&loop=0&api=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&color=ff4600&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&player_id=vimeovideo'" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>


<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

var iframe = $('#vimeovideo')[0],
    player = $f(iframe);

player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
});

  function onFinish(id) {
   window.location.href = 'http://xxxHEREISMYWEBSITExxx.com/portfolio/';
} 

});
</script>
```

The video plays fine, and at the end it does nothing. Why the redirect is not working? If do INSPECT, the console shows me the error:

> froogaloop2.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready'
>   of undefined

I looked up for that and there is a modified version of frogaloop that does not gives this error. Tried that one too, no success.

Can someone help me further? There is no more information on the net.

There are other websites that have this working with WP, tried to copy their JS code but its the same.

Comment: the problem is your copying code without reading it, `iframe = $('#vimeovideo')[0]` would much prefer if there was ONLY 1 ID with this name on the page....at the moment it will return the div wrapper around the iframe

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. I see, yes the extra DIV wrapper around the iframe should be there. I forgot from all the tests I did. I removed it now but still no luck. :(
(EDITED OUT IN QUESTION)

Comment: the error sounds like you have not included jquery

Comment: OK SOMEHOW SOLVED.  It seems that froogaloop is just not working as it should. But for many people it works... no idea why. Now I found this other script:  https://github.com/jrue/Vimeo-jQuery-API   and it works !